# cat /proc/cpuinfo shows 3.00GHz model but 1400.000 cpu MHz?

Tags: performance, intel, central-processing-unit

I ran this command on ssh to see CPU info: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
And it says:

```
...
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
stepping        : 3
cpu MHz         : 1400.000
cache size      : 2048 KB
...
```

Why is cpu Mhz 1400 ? Wasn't it supposed to say 3000Mhz ?
OS is CentOS 6.0

Comment: Note that it is also possible to have [CPU higher than maximum](https://superuser.com/questions/837178/cpu-higher-than-maximum).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the 1400 means that at which speed the processor is running RIGHT now.
3000 is the Max cpu speed.

Comment: +1 This. And the reason is cpu throttling, which makes you have a smaller electricity bill and helps saving penguins. It's a feature that "scales down" the speed at which the CPU completes operational cycles (1.4 billions per second rather than 3 billions) and that uses less power. The cpu is smart enough to "gear up" everytime you need more calculation power, shifting back to 3 Ghz.

Comment: Yes, I just found out now that there is a service that can be started/stopped, I let it on. Interesting.

Comment: ...and the most interesting part is that almost every CPU nowadays will throttle down, since the CPU-speed is normally never the bottleneck.

Comment: Got the answer for what i am exactly looking for. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a service enabled in Linux.
Its is a service called "cpuspeed".

If this service is enabled it will decrease the clock speed as the temperature rises on the processors.

Hence you just need to stop this service in order to get the max clock speed. By default this service will be off on Linux.

```
/etc/init.d/cpuspeed stop
```

Also make sure you switch this service off on boot.

```
chkconfig cpuspeed off
```

After this check the cpuinfo and you will find CPU MHz will be 3.00Ghz